# getting values for PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I have below query in php and want to extract the values from the array and want to use them in a function withing foreach loop. But the values i am getting from the array are wrong. I can not figure out what is wrong here as i am newbie to PHP.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `mlm_pending_transactions` WHERE member_id = $_SESSION[member_id] and cycle=$cycle_number and credited=0 and order_type='upgrade_commission_cash'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);                                                                  
while($data_set = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{                                                                            
   foreach($data_set as $cash_pendings)
   {
      echo $cash_pendings["member_id"]."</br>";
      echo $cash_pendings['tran_amount']."</br>";
      echo $cash_pendings['tran_particulars']."</br>";
      echo $cash_pendings['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you by **formatting your code**.

Comment: Also, "results are wrong" is not useful.  What's wrong about them?  (Show the _actual SQL query run, and maybe show us a bit of the results)

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns an array each time it is called. The array is a row of data from the query. So the fields you want to put out are in the $data_set array NOT the $cash_pendings array (which isn't required).

Comment: Be warned that the mysql_ extension that  you've used was ***REMOVED*** from PHP version 7. If a server that you use runs PHP 7.0 or newer your code will be broken

Comment: Please check this https://prnt.sc/jbqgd2 to see my actual problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The deprecation happened a long time ago. It beggars belief that you might still be using such archaic and insecure code

Answer (score -1):

All you need are the values from the array returned by mysql_fetch_array()

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `mlm_pending_transactions` WHERE member_id = $_SESSION[member_id] and cycle=$cycle_number and credited=0 and order_type='upgrade_commission_cash'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);                                                                  
while($data_set = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{                                                                        
      echo $data_set["member_id"]."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_amount']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_particulars']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['id'];
}
```

Note if the field names are wrong (they are case sensitive) then the values will not be returned.

You could use print_r($data_set) to check on the field names returned if you are not sure.

EDIT - Changes for your actual error.

Absolute minimum. Note not tested so maybe some typos.

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT * 
    FROM `mlm_pending_transactions` 
    WHERE member_id = $_SESSION[member_id] 
    AND cycle = $cycle_number 
    AND credited = 0 
    AND order_type = 'upgrade_commission_cash'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);   

while($data_set = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{                                                                        
      echo $data_set["member_id"]."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_amount']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_particulars']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['id'];

    $date = date("m/d/Y");
    $time = strtotime("now");

    $add_cash = $affiliate->add_fin_tran($data_set["member_id"],
                                $data_set["tran_amount"],
                                0,
                                $data_set["tran_particulars"],
                                "upgrade_commision_cash",
                                1);

    $sql2 = "UPDATE mlm_pending_transactions
        SET credit = 1,
        credited_date = '$date',
        credited_time = '$time'
        WHERE id = ".$data_set["id"];

    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

}

?>
```

However, as others have said you are using the deprecated mysql_* function. Further you have zero protection from SQL injection.

You should use one of the newer methods of accessing the databases. Generally either the mysqli_* functions or the pdo based functions. Note to use these you will also need to switch the function to connect to the database (to the matching ones).

For example, using mysqli_ functions (you can also use these using object orientated syntax):-

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM `mlm_pending_transactions` 
    WHERE member_id = ?
    AND cycle = ?
    AND credited = ? 
    AND order_type = ?";
$statement = mysqli_prepare($db_connection, $sql); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'iiis', $_SESSION['member_id'], $cycle_number, 0, 'upgrade_commission_cash');
mysqli_execute($statement);   
$result = mysqli_get_result($statement);   

while($data_set = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{                                                                        
      echo $data_set["member_id"]."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_amount']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_particulars']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['id'];

    $date = date("m/d/Y");
    $time = strtotime("now");

    $add_cash = $affiliate->add_fin_tran($data_set["member_id"],
                                $data_set["tran_amount"],
                                0,
                                $data_set["tran_particulars"],
                                "upgrade_commision_cash",
                                1);

    $sql2 = "UPDATE mlm_pending_transactions
        SET credit = ?,
        credited_date = ?,
        credited_time = ?
        WHERE id = ?";

    $statement2 = mysqli_prepare($db_connection, $sql2);    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement2, 'issi', 1, $date, $time, $data_set["id"]);
    $result2 = mysqli_execute($statement2);   


}

?>
```

Using the object orientated syntax:-

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM `mlm_pending_transactions` 
    WHERE member_id = ?
    AND cycle = ?
    AND credited = ? 
    AND order_type = ?";
$statement = $db_connection->prepare($sql); 
$statement->bind_param('iiis', $_SESSION['member_id'], $cycle_number, 0, 'upgrade_commission_cash');
$statement->execute();   
$result = $statement->get_result();   

while($data_set = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{                                                                        
      echo $data_set["member_id"]."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_amount']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['tran_particulars']."</br>";
      echo $data_set['id'];

    $date = date("m/d/Y");
    $time = strtotime("now");

    $add_cash = $affiliate->add_fin_tran($data_set["member_id"],
                                $data_set["tran_amount"],
                                0,
                                $data_set["tran_particulars"],
                                "upgrade_commision_cash",
                                1);

    $sql2 = "UPDATE mlm_pending_transactions
        SET credit = ?,
        credited_date = ?,
        credited_time = ?
        WHERE id = ?";

    $statement2 = $db_connection->mysqli_prepare($sql2);    
    $statement2->bind_param('issi', 1, $date, $time, $data_set["id"]);
    $result2 = $statement2->execute();   


}

?>
```

Comment: Please copy and paste this http://prntscr.com/jbqgd2 in your brower to see my problem. Thanks for reply.

Comment: The foreach loop is not necessary. It can go in the while loop directly. But you are also using $result = mysql_query($sql); within the while loop, which will over write the result set that you are looping through. Hence never getting to the 2nd record.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to achieve my result?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Kickstart